# Adobe LiveCycle convert PDF to TIFF = very low resolution TIFF

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, tiff, livecycle

When using Adobe LiveCycle's [ConvertPdfServiceClient toImage operation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/WorkbenchHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb3ef3122812826be91c4-8000.html#WS92d06802c76abadb-1cc35bda128261a20dd-7b52) (in Java) to convert a text-heavy PDF to a TIFF image, the output TIFF image is very low resolution, despite setting Resolution to "300" and ImageSizeHeight & ImageSizeWidth to PageSize.LETTER dimensions.

How can I get LiveCycle to give me a higher resolution TIFF?

My source PDF is 8.5" x 11" (Letter size). It is text-based (not just an image inside a PDF).

This is my spec object:

```
ToImageOptionsSpec spec = new ToImageOptionsSpec(); 
spec.setImageConvertFormat(ImageConvertFormat.TIFF); 
spec.setGrayScaleCompression(GrayScaleCompression.None); 
spec.setMultiPageTiff(true);
spec.setColorSpace(ColorSpace.Monochrome); 
spec.setResolution("300");
spec.setMonochrome(MonochromeCompression.CCITTG4); 
spec.setGrayScalePolicy(GrayScalePolicy.Off); 
spec.setImageSizeHeight(PageSize.Letter.getHeight());
spec.setImageSizeWidth(PageSize.Letter.getWidth());
```

The TIFF output file is:

- Resolution: 612 x 792
- DPI: 300 x 300
- Print Size: 5.2 x 6.7 cm; 2.0 x 2.6 inches
- Colors: 2 (1 BitsPerPixel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the calls to setImageSizeHeight and setImageSizeWidth did the trick. Leaving those unassigned seems to allow them to inherit the source PDF's dimensions, and then the height/width of the resulting image is set based on the setResolution value.

```
ToImageOptionsSpec spec = new ToImageOptionsSpec(); 
spec.setImageConvertFormat(ImageConvertFormat.TIFF); 
spec.setGrayScaleCompression(GrayScaleCompression.None); 
spec.setMultiPageTiff(true);
spec.setColorSpace(ColorSpace.Monochrome); 
spec.setResolution("300");
spec.setMonochrome(MonochromeCompression.CCITTG4); 
spec.setGrayScalePolicy(GrayScalePolicy.Off); 
//spec.setImageSizeHeight(PageSize.Letter.getHeight());
//spec.setImageSizeWidth(PageSize.Letter.getWidth());
```

The TIFF output file is now:

- Resolution: 2550 x 3300
- DPI: 300 x 300
- Print Size: 21.6 x 27.9 cm; 8.5 x 11.0 inches
- Colors: 2 (1 BitsPerPixel)